# R portable: not able to install some packages

Tags: r

I have the Rportable 3.3.1 version. Some packages (such as ggplot2) were installed without problem. But some packages that must be compiled from binaries cannot be installed. I have Rtools version 3.4.0.1962 installed on my computer but it seems that it is not detected by Rportable.
The packages that create a problem are:

- httpuv
- jsonlite
- sourcetools

Which all return the following error:

```
>install.packages("jsonlite")
Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran: ‘jsonlite’
These will not be installed
```

How can I tell Rportable where to locate Rtools to compile packages source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use Rtools you have to add path to Rtools binaries to PATH environment variable of your OS. In Windows, you can do it in settings dialog (System properties->Advanced->Env Variables->User variables PATH) or by running

```
$userPath = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "User")
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path",$userPath + ";E:\Rtools\bin;E:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin", "User")
```

in PowerShell. I assume you are on 64-bit Windows and have Rtools installed on a flashdisk mounted to E. You do NOT need to have admin priviladges.

Comment: Btw. I cannot install any binary package from CRAN today on any windows machine. It seems to be a problem on CRAN.

Comment: Yes there appears to be a CRAN issue possibly related: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-package-devel/2016q3/001079.html